# pythonGroup list of lists by value

Tags: python-3.x

So i have this list of lists:

```
items=[
    ['iss1','ETH','ch1','account'],
    ['iss1','ADA','ch1','account'],
    ['iss1','QNT','ch1','account'],
    ['iss1','TYY','ch1','account'],

    ['iss2','ETH','ch2','account'],
    ['iss2','ADA','ch2','account'],
    ['iss2','QNT','ch2','account'],
    ['iss2','TYY','ch2','account'],

    ['iss3','ETH','ch3','account'],
    ['iss3','ADA','ch3','account'],
    ['iss3','QNT','ch3','account'],
    ['iss3','TYY','ch3','account'],
]
```

Someone can help me how i can group it to look like this ? i WANT TO group them by first value

Soo, like that:

```
groupped = [
    [
        'iss1',
        'ch1',
        'account',
        [
        'ETH', 'ADA', 'QNT', 'TYY'
        ]
    ],
    
    [
        'iss2',
        'ch2',
        'account',
        [
        'ETH', 'ADA', 'QNT', 'TYY'
        ]
    ],

    [
        'iss3',
        'ch3',
        'account',
        [
        'ETH', 'ADA', 'QNT', 'TYY'
        ]
    ],
]
```

Basically i want to take all lists that has safe first key and add them in a new list with MMM/CCC first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
items = [
    ['CCC','asset_SSS','CH_1','dis_1',],
    ['CCC','asset_FDF','CH_1','dis_1',],
    ['CCC','asset_D8F','CH_1','dis_1',],
    ['MMM','asset_SSS','CH_1','dis_1',],
    ['MMM','asset_FDF','CH_1','dis_1',],
    ['MMM','asset_D8F','CH_1','dis_1',],
]

grouped = []
temp_dict = {}

for item in items:
    key = item[0]
    values = item[1:]
    if key in temp_dict:
        temp_dict[key].append(values)
    else:
        temp_dict[key] = [values]

for key, values in temp_dict.items():
    grouped.append([key] + values)

print("Grouped= ",grouped)
```

Output:

```
Grouped= [['CCC',
 ['asset_SSS', 'CH_1', 'dis_1'],
 ['asset_FDF', 'CH_1', 'dis_1'],
 ['asset_D8F', 'CH_1', 'dis_1']], 
['MMM',
 ['asset_SSS', 'CH_1', 'dis_1'],
 ['asset_FDF', 'CH_1', 'dis_1'],
 ['asset_D8F', 'CH_1', 'dis_1']]]
```

Or using [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import groupby

items = [
    ['CCC','asset_SSS','CH_1','dis_1',],
    ['CCC','asset_FDF','CH_1','dis_1',],
    ['CCC','asset_D8F','CH_1','dis_1',],
    ['MMM','asset_SSS','CH_1','dis_1',],
    ['MMM','asset_FDF','CH_1','dis_1',],
    ['MMM','asset_D8F','CH_1','dis_1',],
]

grouped = []
for key, group in groupby(items, lambda x: x[0]):
    grouped.append([key] + [item[1:] for item in group])

print("Grouped= ",grouped)
```

Output:

```
Grouped= [['CCC',
 ['asset_SSS', 'CH_1', 'dis_1'],
 ['asset_FDF', 'CH_1', 'dis_1'],
 ['asset_D8F', 'CH_1', 'dis_1']], 
['MMM',
 ['asset_SSS', 'CH_1', 'dis_1'],
 ['asset_FDF', 'CH_1', 'dis_1'],
 ['asset_D8F', 'CH_1', 'dis_1']]]
```

### UPDATE

```
items = [
    ['iss1', 'ETH', 'ch1', 'account'],
    ['iss1', 'ADA', 'ch1', 'account'],
    ['iss1', 'QNT', 'ch1', 'account'],
    ['iss1', 'TYY', 'ch1', 'account'],
    ['iss2', 'ETH', 'ch2', 'account'],
    ['iss2', 'ADA', 'ch2', 'account'],
    ['iss2', 'QNT', 'ch2', 'account'],
    ['iss2', 'TYY', 'ch2', 'account'],
    ['iss3', 'ETH', 'ch3', 'account'],
    ['iss3', 'ADA', 'ch3', 'account'],
    ['iss3', 'QNT', 'ch3', 'account'],
    ['iss3', 'TYY', 'ch3', 'account'],
]

grouped = {}

for item in items:
    key = item[0]
    if key not in grouped:
        grouped[key] = [key, item[2], item[3], [item[1]]]
    else:
        grouped[key][3].append(item[1])

grouped = list(grouped.values())

print(grouped)
```

output:

```
[    ['iss1', 'ch1', 'account', ['ETH', 'ADA', 'QNT', 'TYY']],
    ['iss2', 'ch2', 'account', ['ETH', 'ADA', 'QNT', 'TYY']],
    ['iss3', 'ch3', 'account', ['ETH', 'ADA', 'QNT', 'TYY']]
]
```